# Poles and Zeroes - Z Domain

Tags: filters, homework

2nd order Butterworth transfer function:

$$H(z) = \frac{ 0.0201z^2 + 0.0402z + 0.0201 } { z^2 - 1.5609z + 0.6413 }$$

I'm a bit uncertain about the factorization at the denominator. Here's what I have so far:

\begin{eqnarray*}
H(z) &=& \frac{ 0.0201(z^2 +2z + 1)  }{ z^2 - 1.5609z + 0.6413 }\\
 &=& \frac{ 0.0201(z + 1)(z + 1)  }{ z(z - 1.5609) + 0.6413 }
\end{eqnarray*}
Zeros : $z + 1 = 0$, zero at $z = -1$.

How can I find the poles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the same thing you did for the zeros. The denominator is

$$f(z) =z^2 - 1.5609z + 0.6413$$

So to find the poles of $H(z)$, you should find the roots for that polynomial. Since it is a 2nd grade one, it's easy as we can use the quadratic formula

$$z_{1,2} = \frac{-(- 1.5609) \pm \sqrt{(- 1.5609)^2 - 4 \cdot1\cdot 0.6413}}{2\cdot1}$$

This returns the two complex poles of the transfer function:

$$z_1 \approx 0.78+i0.18$$
$$z_2 \approx 0.78-i0.18$$

Answer (score 0):

use the quadratic formula.  you know:

$$ a \, x^2 \ + \ b \, x \ + \ c \ = \ 0 $$

$\implies$

$$ x = \begin{cases}
 \frac{-b \, \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4 a c}}{2\,a}  \quad \text{if } b^2 \ge 4 a c \\
  \\
 \frac{-b \, \pm j \sqrt{4 a c -b^2}}{2\,a}  \quad \text{if } b^2 < 4 a c\\
\end{cases}$$